# How to display combo box selectedvalue?

Tags: vb.net

I am filling a combo box with dataset:

```
ComboName.Items.Clear()
DS = New DataSet
DS.Tables.Add(New DataTable("DEMAND"))
DA = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from DEMAND", CON)
DA.Fill(DS, "DEMAND")
ComboName.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
ComboName.DisplayMember = "name"
ComboName.ValueMember = "id"
```

Now I want to retrieve address with the help of `ValueMember`:

```
Private Sub ComboName_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboName.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim I as Integer = CType(ComboName.SelectedValue.ToString(), Integer)

    CMD = New SqlCommand("select * from DEMAND where id=" & I, CON)
    RDR = CMD.ExecuteReader()
    If RDR.Read Then
        TxtAdrs.Text = RDR!adrs
    End If
End Sub
```

But here i am getting an error :

> Conversion from string `"System.Data.DataRowView"` to type `'Integer'` is not valid.

Can anybody tell what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `ComboName.SelectedValue.ToString()` returns the name of the class

```
"System.Data.DataRowView"
```

which is the default behaviour of ToString()

try getting a specific column from the DataRowView.

SelectedItem is the data object that is bound to the ComboBox's data source, which in this case is DataRowView.

You need to cast SelectedItem to DataRowView, then retrieve the appropriate value from it.

You can do this as follows:

```
DataRowView oDataRowView = ComboName.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
string sValue = "";

if (oDataRowView != null) {
   sValue = oDataRowView.Row["YourFieldName"] as string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. I have been googling since 6 hours. God Bless You..

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is in this line

```
Dim I as Integer = CType(ComboName.SelectedValue.ToString(), Integer)
```

Use like this

```
Dim I as Integer = CType(ComboName.SelectedValue, Integer)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried, but slight different error : Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

try to declare it as an object instead of integer.

```
dim selecteditem as object
selecteditem = comboname.selectedvalue
```